# Cant access userManager outside controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have .net identity setup in my startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And this works fine in the controller with constructor injection.

However If I tell .net to inject another class, ie:

```
services.AddScoped<WebSocketEvent>();
```

and then in the class:

```
public class WebSocketEvent
{
    IHubContext<SignalHub> _hubcontext;
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public WebSocketEvent(IHubContext<SignalHub> hubcontext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _hubcontext = hubcontext;
        _userManager = userManager;     
    }
}
```

It cant make/inject the userManager and I get:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[WebSockets.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'WebSockets.Services.WebSocketEvent'.

Comment: Is `WebSockets.Models.ApplicationUser` the *only* class in your project that's called `ApplicationUser` or do you have another `ApplicationUser` in a different namespace?

Comment: Yes only one (this is just the default site that .net creates from new in visual studio with .net identity and MVC)

Comment: Is there an inner exception as part of this exception?

Comment: Dont get the error in visual studio, only shows a webpage with : InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[WebSockets.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'WebSockets.Services.WebSocketEvent'.  - Cant see anything labeled inner exception

Comment: @CerIs I have checked with the code you provided in a test project! Its working as expected! My project ASP.NET Core version is 2.2.0 Preview2

Comment: Sorry, original answer is correct - I had a duplicate applicationUser class many levels below in project that causing the problem